# CIVICRM release path process

Tags: upgrade, joomla, paths, release

I am currently on CIVICRM 5.463 under Joomla 3.10.11.  As I am relatively knew to the CIVICRM world, is there a specific release upgrade process (other than taking backups) that I should be aware of?  Any specific gotchas that I should watch out for in doing an upgrade?  Are there any issues with me upgrading directly to 5.55 from 5.463?  Any concerns about associated extensions?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/joomla/ and https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/version-specific/

Comment: You might want to convert your comment into an answer, @demerit .

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/joomla, which has steps for joomla and https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/version-specific which has generic information.